# Installing Facebook SDK - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've stuck on this for a while... How do I install the Facebook SDK??

I imported a group called FBConnect that contains 9 header files (that's all I've done), but I find all of these tutorials telling me to create an object like this...

```
Facebook *facebook;
```

But I don't have a Facebook class at all... How can I do this in my iPhone app/project? Below is what I really want to do and this is all...

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638955/facebook-ios-sdk-get-list-of-friends
```

Comment: Did you import the headers? Something like `#import <FacebookHeaderName/FacebookHeaderName.h>`

Comment: Note that the class name doesn't have to be the name of the header file. You should have the class

Comment: All I did was this...#import "FBConnect.h"

Comment: Its in my xcode project but it's causing errors because I user ARC..

Comment: To disable ARC for the Facebook SDK code files try following this guide: http://www.leesilver.net/1/post/2011/8/disabling-arc-on-certain-files-in-xcode.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you downloaded the official SDK from this [link](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) you should follow this [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#sdk). It has the Facebook class and all you need to fetch the friends list.