# iOS Facebook SDK 3.1 Retrieve friend birthday returning null

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

I'm trying to retrieve birthday data of facebook friends, but it's returning null.
I'm using this code:

```
FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];
[friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                  NSDictionary* result,
                                  NSError *error) {
    NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSLog(@"Found: %i friends", friends.count);
    for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend in friends) {
        NSLog(@"I have a friend named %@ - birthday %@", friend.name, friend.birthday);
    }
}];
```

Friend name is ok, but friend birthday or all data that is not one of the basics friends data is returning null.
Note i'm already added user_birthday and friends_birthday permissions in facebook.com app page and in openSession method (login):

```
- (void)openSession
{

    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"user_birthday",
                            @"friends_birthday",
                            nil];


    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session,
       FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
         [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
     }];
 }
```

Needing some help here, i've already tried everything.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I have the same problem and i solve this way.

- First of all, be sure that you have the correct permissions.

  ```
   NSArray *permissions = @[@"user_birthday", @"friends_hometown",
                          @"friends_birthday", @"friends_location"];
  [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler: .....
  ```
- Then, DO NOT USE requestForMyFriends. I try in several ways ( changing the FBRequest and this kind of things
- Check the permissions and be sure that it was the permissions you need.

  ```
  NSLog(@"permissions::%@",FBSession.activeSession.permissions);
  ```
- Now generate the FBRequest this way.

  ```
  FBRequest *friendRequest = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"me/friends?fields=name,picture,birthday,location"];
   [ friendRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
      NSArray *data = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
      for (FBGraphObject<FBGraphUser> *friend in data) {
          NSLog(@"%@:%@", [friend name],[friend birthday]);
   }}];
  ```

I finally get this data. I hope it helps you

Comment: here is a problem while write the following code
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler: .....

The Problem is that "loginViewFetchedUserInfo" method continuously called .. so i remove that code and app works fine

Comment: Now I am using iOS Facebook SDK 3.2 and unable to get friend list. I can Invite friends as well as I can get friends which is used same app, but unable to get my all friends list. Is there any change from facebook side?

Comment: Awesome, thanks -- this still works as of July 1, 2014 (iOS SDK v3.15.1). [result objectForKey:@"data"] also includes a URL to a thumbnail for the friend's FB avatar.

Comment: I following this instruction but got the error:`Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed`

Comment: and: `code = 2500; message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";type = OAuthException;` please help me to know what I am doing wrong? thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you it helped me in the way of path i was using @"/me/friends" instead of this @"me/friends". so the problem happend. Anyways the solution i found by seeing your answer also. so +1 for you

Answer (score 2):

In v2.0 of the Graph API, you cannot get a person's friends birthdays - the `friends_birthday` permission has been deprecated.

Read more about these changes here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog