# Facebook- friend's birthday returns null value

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I used below objective-c code to retrive friend list, id and birthday from facebook which works fine for friend list and id but returns null value for friend's birthday.

```
FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];
[friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                              NSDictionary* result,
                              NSError *error) {
NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
NSLog(@"Found: %i friends", friends.count);
for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend in friends) {
    NSLog(@"I have a friend named %@ with id %@  with Birthdate %@", friend.name, friend.id, friend.birthday);
}
}];
```

I also set permissions for friend_birthday but still it returning null value for friend's birthday. Can anyone help me in retrieving friend's birthdate instead of null value? Thanks in advance

Comment: (arey monya bhetle na answer...) finally got the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170850/ios-facebook-sdk-3-1-retrieve-friend-birthday-returning-null

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you added the permission 'user_birthday', it provides access to the birthday with year as the birthday property

Comment: it returning me user's birthday properly but not able to return his friend's birthday

Comment: am also facing the same problem.I am using facebook SDK 3.1, so it the problem or something else?

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                @"user_birthday",@"friends_hometown",
                                @"friends_birthday",@"friends_location",
                                nil];
 [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler: .....

 FBRequest *friendRequest = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"me/friends?fields=name,picture,birthday,location"];
 [ friendRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) 
{
   NSArray *data = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
   for (FBGraphObject<FBGraphUser> *friend in data) 
   {
      NSLog(@"%@:%@", [friend name],[friend birthday]);
    }
}];
```