# How we can get user's birthday using facebook graph api?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get birth of date of logged-in facebook user . i tried the code mentioned on facebook developer website , but still i didn't got birthday date .

I have tried the code below to get user info:

```
  [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // Success! Include your code to handle the results here
            NSLog(@"user info: %@", result);
        } else {
            // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
            // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
        }
          }];
```

Comment: Show the part where you're issueing the request.

Comment: self.facebookLoginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile",@"user_birthday", @"email", @"user_friends"];

Comment: That's the permission request. Where's the actual call to the Graph API?

Answer (score 1):

**According to facebook**,

- Any permissions other then "user_friends", "public_profile" and
  "email" require **Facebook app review**.
- Although If you login with **administrators's account**, you will get all the information you need for development purposes.

Comment: I have logged in using admin account , but still i am not getting birthday :(

Comment: You have to request "user_birthday" with other permissions. Are you requesting it?

Comment: self.facebookLoginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile",@"user_birthday", @"email", @"user_friends"];

Comment: Try following this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170850/ios-facebook-sdk-3-1-retrieve-friend-birthday-returning-null