# How to get friend list from Facebook with parameters gender, user_likes, user_birthday,

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I have tried tutorials on this site https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/run-fql-queries-ios-sdk/, but I can not get it to work - maybe I made a mistake.

Maybe anyone else has some other tutorial - step by step or maybe source code?

Comment: when I run simulator it shows me the buttons but nothing happens when i push the button

Comment: Can you get the completed sample (https://github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.1-howtos/tree/master/FQLHowTo) running?

Comment: @CAbernathy, Thanks. I try this sample in Xcode, I see friend-list (all output - window), but on the simulator nothings show. Do you have any Idea?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/W8yAu.png

Comment: You hit upon a corner case that showed a bug. The toolbar's covering the first friend and since you only have one friend in your result, you didn't see anything. I'll post the answer (bug fixed basically) so you can accept it if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug where the toolbar was hiding the first entry in the tableview. The fix in the tutorial was not to add the toolbar to the tableview. In this case it was added as a UITableView section header view. Go ahead and try it out again.

Comment: Check out github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.1-howtos/tree/master/FQLHowTo onc e more and you'll find the changed file.

Answer (score 0):

Try solutions found in this SO question:

[Facebook iOS SDK - get friends list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638955/facebook-ios-sdk-get-list-of-friends)

Good luck!