# Facebook SDK for iOS - Questions about ID's

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

Just now beginning to work with the Facebook SDK for iOS, and have a few questions. I can display a list of all friends, using the code found here: [Facebook iOS SDK - get friends list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638955/facebook-ios-sdk-get-list-of-friends). I see that each freind has an ID, and have a the following questions:

1. If I am signed into FB account A, and see that friend B has ID 123, if I sign into FB account C, will friend B still have the ID of 123?
2. Assuming the answer to question 1 is yes, that would lead me to believe that each account has a unique ID. If so, then how do I find the current FB account's ID that is shown to other friends?

Comment: 1). The ID's are assigned like keys to the users, hence they dont change. They remain same. However, from you question, it seems like you wish to use the ID generated for one user for another user. I would not appreciate that, its not safe. I suggest you to rethink of some other way to achieve your goal, without the dependency on other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All user IDs are unique and do not change (and are also public information).

If you want to find out the ID of the current user that's logged in, make a graph request for "/me", or use this method:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.5/class/FBRequestConnection#startForMeWithCompletionHandler%3A

And look for the "id" property in the result.